# mysql query does not work on different files -php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

i might be doing some idiot mistake, but i could not figure that out. i have some values coming from html and wanna insert into mysql db. problem is, the very same query does not work in regular php file (that includes other queries), but when i try on an independent php file, it does. here is a sample of the code:

```
    $sql15="insert into body 
            (Article_ID, Article_Title) 
            values
            ('$article_id', '".$_POST['Article_Title']."') ";
    mysql_query($sql15);
```

as i mentioned, the very same code works when i just copy this snippet to a new php file, and it works smoothly.. as you see, there are 20+ insert with the same php, because there are 25+ tables, but data is not much. first 14 query and following 7 queries do work by the way. 
do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sanitize user input! see [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Which error do you receive? Check it and show us please

Comment: @Czechnology..well, i am trying myself. development step has not done yet(because of this issue).
Marco.. there is no error at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things to check and do.

- [Sanitize user input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):
  `"('$article_id', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Article_Title'])."')";`
  You might also want to check if the value is what you expect.
- Is your `$article_id` correct for column `Article_ID`?
- Are your table and column names correct?
- Check for errors:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql15);
if (!$res)
  echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link);
```

- Show us you complete query:
  `echo $sql15;`

Comment: well, thanks.. but how come it works when i use the very same query in an another php file, with the very same input ?

Comment: Well, that's "simple" - you're doing something differently. Either you modify the variables (`$article_id` or `$_POST['Article_Title']`) before using them in the query or you initialize the database connection differently. Or something else. That's what debugging is for - go step by step until you figure it out or post here more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would suggest you to write your insert query like below

```
$sql15="insert into body SET Article_ID = '$article_id', Article_Title = '".$_POST['Article_Title']."'";
echo $sql15;
mysql_query($sql15);
```

so that each time when you add new column to database it would be easy for u to change insert query. echo your query and see it in browser. in it seems to o.k then copy it and paste it in SQL section under your phpmyadmin (see you are choosing proper database) and run it. if one row inserted successfully then your query is alright.

I hope this would help you a little.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql15="insert into body 
            (Article_ID, Article_Title) 
            values
            ('$article_id', '".$_POST['Article_Title']."') ";
    mysql_query($sql15) or die(mysql_error());
```

use like this u will be get the error. then u will be find the issue

Comment: thanks Vijayan, i am echoing errors, but i do not know how, why, but there was no error at all. maybe i should check my php install,,??

Answer (score 0):

I think using mysql_real_escape_string may solve your problem.I also recommend you to store your form data in a string.

> $article_title= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Article_Title']);
>
> $sql15="insert into body
>
> ```
>         (Article_ID, Article_Title) 
>         values
>         ('$article_id', '$article_title') ";
> mysql_query($sql15) or die(mysql_error());
> ```